# Error on updating entity with a computed column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I want to update an entity that has a computed column. Unfortunately I get a `SqlException`:

> SqlException: Column 'inserted.OpenCount' cannot be referenced in the OUTPUT clause because the column definition contains a subquery or references a function that performs user or system data access. A function is assumed by default to perform data access if it is not schemabound. Consider removing the subquery or function from the column definition or removing the column from the OUTPUT clause.

when I try to do this:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}/[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetPublished(int id, string returnUrl)
{
    // load article
    var article = await Data.Articles.SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id);

    if (article == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    // toggle published 
    if (!article.IsPublished)
        article.IsPublished = true;
    else
        article.IsPublished = false;

    await Data.SaveChangesAsync();

    // redirect
    if (returnUrl != null)
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

I did try to exclude this column with `[NotMapped]` attribute but this has not helped.

Is there way to fix that without changing database structure?

Here is how this column is declared:

```
[Table("Articles")]
public class Article : IdEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets publish date and time.
    /// </summary>
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Дата публикации")]
    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets article name.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Название")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите название")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Название должно быть не более 50 символов")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets URL name.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Название в URL")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Название в URL должно быть не длиннее 50 символов")]
    [RegularExpression(RegexConstants.UrlName, ErrorMessage = "Название в URL может содержать только символы латинского алфавита, цифры, символы тире и подчеркивания")]
    public virtual string UrlName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets article full text.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Текст")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Введите текст")]
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets if article is published. If not when one should not be available on public website.
    /// </summary>
    [Display(Name = "Опубликована")]
    public virtual bool IsPublished { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets nubmer of article opens.
    /// </summary>
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Количество открытий")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public virtual int OpenCount { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: A little note: 2nd `if` could be replaced to `article.IsPublished = !article.IsPublished;` Could you post table definition for `Article` entity? How computed column is declared?

Comment: @Dennis, you're right, but please, let's discuss the subject.

Comment: 1) Why do you use `[NotMapped]`? If property is mapped to computed column, it is still mapped; 2) could you post *table* definition, not a class definition?

Comment: Dennis, let's move to the chat in 30 minutes?

Comment: NotMapped because I'd like to avoid tracking of this column, I expect this solve problem, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this issue for a good few days. My research showed that at this point, there are two ways to identify a field as "computed" for EF.

1. For individual updates (Add(), Addrange(), updates via DbContext), the EF will not save but only retrieve the value of that column.
2. For Bulk updates, the EF.BulkExtensions will use a mix of the Fluent Configuration and the Data Annotation on the column. Setting PropertiesToExclude or PropertiesToInclude will still try to OUTPUT the values from the MERGE query that is triggered after the data is bulk loaded into a TEMP table, thus causing the same Exception.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations
https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/blob/master/EFCore.BulkExtensions/TableInfo.cs

I ended up adding a SPROC to address the calculation of the computed column and simply use it as any other bound to DB model property.

I am sure triggers could also work, although they would not be my first choice

Comment: This is only partially related, and apart from that, too sketchy to be really meaningful. OP's issue is that the property is both `[NotMapped]` and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`. That doesn't make sense, because setting `DatabaseGenerated` is the opposite of not mapping the property.